# python program to insert jpg files into a google slides presentation

Tags: python, google-slides-api, google-slides

NEXT ATTEMPT:
Assume that I have a directory with jpg image files, and the oldest image (time stamp) should be slide #1, and the newest image slide #N to be inserted in a google slides presentation. I am using [the API](https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/python)
The installation on windows 10 was apparently Okay.
The issue reported before has been fixed, thanks to the person that helped me.

Next, this python code is to check if the API works for me: (modified compared to the first time I created this post)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import library_JP

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
#SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly']
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations']

# The ID of a sample presentation.
PRESENTATION_ID = '1EAYk18WDjIG-zp_0vLm3CsfQh_i8eXc67Jo2O9C6Vuc'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Slides API.
    Prints the number of slides and elments in a sample presentation.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Slides API
    IMAGE_URL = ('https://www.google.com/images/branding/'
             'googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
    requests = []
    page_id = '3b330c04-6eb2-11eb-9439-0242ac130002'
    image_id = 'MyImage_01'
    emu4M = {
    'magnitude': 4000000,
    'unit': 'EMU',
            }
    requests.append({
     'createImage': {
        'objectId': image_id,
        'url': IMAGE_URL,
        'elementProperties': {
            'pageObjectId': page_id,
            'size': {
                'height': emu4M,
                'width': emu4M
            },
            'transform': {
                'scaleX': 1,
                'scaleY': 1,
                'translateX': 100000,
                'translateY': 100000,
                'unit': 'EMU'
                         }
            }
                    }
                    })
    title = 'JP_february13-2021 '
    body = {
    'title': title, 'requests': requests
    }
#    presentation = slides_service.presentations() \
    presentation = service.presentations() \
    .create(body=body).execute()
    print('Created presentation with ID: {0}'.format(
    presentation.get('presentationId')))
    response = slides_service.presentations() \
    .batchUpdate(presentationId=presentation_id, body=body).execute()
    create_image_response = response.get('replies')[0].get('createImage')
    print('Created image with ID: {0}'.format(
    create_image_response.get('objectId')))





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note I have included the code at https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/master/slides/snippets/slides_snippets.py
as follows:

```
import library_JP
```

There is now a new issue:

```
python quickstart_JP1.py
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=162352680285-0i0fmpq50gqgsm1d796mmdim3c3oe874.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53854%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fpresentations&state=I7dMBbrWmZjVXBwyk0i1mAqLFWonhS&access_type=offline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart_JP1.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart_JP1.py", line 77, in main
    .create(body=body).execute()
  File "C:\Users\joepareti54\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\joepareti54\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.'}]}]">
```

Comment: From your error message, it is found that the reason of your error message is due to the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly`. When you want to use the method of `presentations().create()`, it is required to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations`. But I cannot understand about the relationship between your script and `Assume that I have a directory with jpg image files, and the oldest image (time stamp) should be slide #1, and the newest image slide #N to be inserted in a google slides presentation.`. Can I ask you about the goal of your this question?

Comment: thanks to your advice I could fix the problem. I have then posted  a modified version of the code that leads to a next exception

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: It looks like the issue here is that the `field` parameter is missing from the request. However, I am not exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

this code works; it is important to delete token.pickle and to have the following entry:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations']
```

instead of

````
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly'] ```
````

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
#SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly']
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations']

# The ID of a sample presentation.
PRESENTATION_ID = '1EAYk18WDjIG-zp_0vLm3CsfQh_i8eXc67Jo2O9C6Vuc'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Slides API.
    Prints the number of slides and elments in a sample presentation.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Slides API
    title = 'JP_february13-2021 '
    body = {
    'title': title
    }
#    presentation = slides_service.presentations() \
    presentation = service.presentations() \
    .create(body=body).execute()
    print('Created presentation with ID: {0}'.format(
    presentation.get('presentationId')))

#    print('The presentation contains {} slides:'.format(len(slides)))
#    for i, slide in enumerate(slides):
#        print('- Slide #{} contains {} elements.'.format(
#            i + 1, len(slide.get('pageElements'))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, the next version where I try to include images in the presentation does
NOT work.